# PHP: CURL is enabled but has no effect

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get data from external website using `cURL` in `PHP` but, somehow it's not working.

I've checked out that `CURL` enable in `phpinfo()`. It shows `cURL` is enabled [image: cURL is enabled]

But, my code is not working.

```
<?php
if (! function_exists ( 'curl_version' )) {
    exit ( "Enable cURL in PHP" );
}

$ch = curl_init ();
$timeout = 0; // 100; // set to zero for no timeout
$myHITurl = "http://www.google.com";
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $myHITurl );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
$file_contents = curl_exec ( $ch );
if (curl_errno ( $ch )) {
    echo curl_error ( $ch );
    curl_close ( $ch );
    exit ();
}
curl_close ( $ch );

// dump output of api if you want during test
echo "$file_contents";
?>
```

It goes timeout.
[image: Connection Timeout]

I'm not using WAMP or XAMPP server. The above code runs directly on the server.
I've no idea what's going wrong.

Comment: which OS you are using?

Comment: The error suggests that curl itself is working. This looks like a firewall issue on the host that is running the script.

Comment: @WisdmLabs server os is `linux`

Comment: My 80 & 443 port are blocked from server side. Thanks to both of you guys for helping me!

Comment: Is DNS issue... check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24967855/curl-6-could-not-resolve-host-google-com-name-or-service-not-known/24987376

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code is perfect, I have tested it on my own server (data center in Texas) and it worked fine.

My guess is that your server IP is banned. Try to fetch a different URL, and see if it works for you. If it does then you are banned, if it doesn't then it might be a firewall configuration issue in your server.

Comment: Let me checkout for `Firewall` issue. but, I can't understand about `IP is banned`. can you tell me in brief. How can I check if my IP is banned.

Comment: I can't tell you for sure if it is banned or not, because it can also be a firewall configuration issue. Another thing you could try is to run `telnet www.google.com 80` in the terminal and see if you can connect. Try fetching a different URL, like http://www.example.com, in your code and see if it works. Good luck!

Comment: My `80` & `443` port are blocked from server side. Thanks for your Answer @Aviram

Answer (score 0):

disable SELinux if you are on Centos or Fedora or any Redhat Distro

```
nano /etc/selinux/config
```

Change

```
SELINUX=enforcing
```

to

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

Comment: On CentOS 8 use "sestatus" instead of "nano /etc/selinux/config" which gives "unknown".