# connecting to docker with curl

Tags: curl, docker

I'm following [this](http://www.ybrikman.com/writing/2015/11/11/running-docker-aws-ground-up/) tutorial on docker which sets up a small hello world server.

This is the expected behavior:

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 training/webapp:latest python app.py
curl http://dockerhost:5000
Hello world!
```

However, I get an error when I run

```
curl http://dockerhost:5000
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: dockerhost
```

I looked at some other answers and tried

```
ping http;//dockerhost:5000
unknown host http://dockerhost:5000

nslookup http://dockerhost:5000
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

netstat -utapen | grep 5000
tcp6       0      0 :::5000                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          251303      -
```

Some stackoverflow answers ([curl: (6) Could not resolve host: google.com; Name or service not known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24967855/curl-6-could-not-resolve-host-google-com-name-or-service-not-known)) were talking about DNS issues (wrong DNS server), but I don't know what to do to see if this is relevant to my problem.

Comment: unless you have dockerhost in your file /etc/hosts or in your DNS, you should not type dockerhost, but 127.0.01 or localhost

Comment: Just a side comment to this question: In some settings you can have an automated assigned IP which one can see with ```docker inspect``` and then a ```curl http://{ip}:{port}``` could work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add

> dockerhost 127.0.0.1

in your hosts file or use 127.0.0.1 to access the container. Also, I recommend using a name in your docker run command as in:

> docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name dockerhost training/webapp:latest python app.py

When you run multiple containers, if you put them in the same network, you can connect to containers from the other containers by the name you give them.

Answer (score 12):

**Motivation and Solution**: You run some service and you want to expose it to the outside world (in default - the container is open and talk to other services if they run together - for example like web application service and some db service like redis/postgress/mongo that are running together on same machine and "talk" to each other) But accesing it in blackbox world is different and try to get in is forbidden. you don't have permission. therefore you should configure the specific port explicitly on your docker command or on your `docker-compose.yml` file the port attribute, and connect through this link:

**For example** lets say on my `docker-compose.yml` file , configure `port` attribute:

```
ports:
  - "0.0.0.0:8080:8080"
```

Verify it using `docker ps` to watch all running containers:

```
CONTAINER ID    IMAGE                          COMMAND                   CREATED        STATUS        PORTS                               NAMES
abc123asd456    someService/someService:lts    "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"    10 weeks ago    Up 10 days    0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 50000/tcp   serviceName
```

and access it directly from localhost: `0.0.0.0:8080`

```
curl -X GET 0.0.0.0:8080/api/some-api-function
```

Answer (score 7):

This is more a `DNS` question.

When you use commands such as `curl`, `ping` or `nslookup` or other commands that open connections to other ends, they expect you to inform the IP Address of the other end, or a name that can be resolved to an IP.

On your case, `dockerhost` is a name, not an IP, and your system can't resolve this name to an IP Address.

There are many solutions, like the one put above.
You can inform your system the IP Address of the name  `dockerhost` but inserting a line in the `/etc/hosts` file (if you're on a Linux box):

```
echo "127.0.0.1 dockerhost" >> /etc/hosts
```

or just edit the file `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` if you're on a Windows machine.

That tells your system that the IP Address of the name `dockerhost` is `127.0.0.1`, which is the same as your `localhost`, or, your own machine.

Now you should be able to `ping` it:

```
ping dockerhost
```

node that `ping` and `nslookup` expect just a name, without the protocol (`http://`) and port (`5000`). `curl` does expect the protocol and port.

Either that or you can use just the IP `127.0.0.1` instead of `dockerhost`.

Answer (score -4):

if you try

> curl name_of_container:5000/path/to/method

(without http://)

should work