# Not able to invoke REST API using curl to the application running within the docker container

Tags: docker, rest, curl, containers

I am invoking REST API using curl for my application running within container.I am unable to access the REST API using curl & getting below message

```
root@2p1aa752bf12f:/# curl 'http://127.0.0.1' -x $http_proxy
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
```

I tried multiple ways from within the container but it is not working:

1. With IPaddress
2. with localhost

However when i do ping test i am able to get the response

```
root@2p1aa752bf12f:/# ping localhost
localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.033 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.015 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.031 ms
```

Also i would want to invoke REST API running on a different container as well.My containers are connected using Bridge network
I can ping it but cannot access REST API using curl.I do not get any response & it hangs

Expecting to invoke REST API from within container & also access REST API exposed in another container

Comment: You are testing port 80, but your comment suggests you are running your server on port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that `ping` and `curl` do different things.

You'll use `ping` command for test IP address, hostname reachability

```
ping localhost # domain name translated into 127.0.0.1 in your system
```

In your case `curl http://127.0.0.1` did something more:

- trying to reach localhost
- trying to establish connection with the 80 port (standard http port)

Your '*localhost*' (your container) did not provide any connection to your  `curl` request avoiding connectivity.

Ensure you have a web server up and running on that `http:<HOST>:<PORT>`

---

**references**:

- similar question -> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887775/connecting-to-docker-with-curl)
- docker web tutorial -> [here](https://www.ybrikman.com/writing/2015/11/11/running-docker-aws-ground-up/)
- `curl` -> linux man page [here](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html)
- `ping` -> official curl man page [here](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ping)