# Curl Could not resolve host in Elasticsearch

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I am learning to using [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/) on Windows recently.

I followed the instructions as [this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/windows.html) said and got stuck at `Checking that Elasticsearch is running`.

I had downloaded the latest [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) binary executable (7.54.0) for windows, but when I copied the following line using the button `COPY AS CURL`:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/?pretty'
```

It gave the error:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 'localhost
```

I had tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24967855/3917161) to disable IPV6 but the problem still remains.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my case, curl somehow doesn't recognize the `'` symbol.

Changing `'` to `"` can fix the problem.

```
curl -XGET "localhost:9200/?pretty"
```

Comment: Coz you're on windows

Comment: Yes, in Windows we should use `"`, while in Linux is `'`. The tutorial didn't update the command for Windows.