# CURL returning Couldn't resolve host in yii

Tags: php, curl, yii

I am trying to call CURL to another localhost project using yii. But in returns `Couldn't resolve host`

However, if I CURL other projects, it works fine. Is there any setting I need to update in the project I want to use CURL?

Here is my code:

```
 $ch = curl_init("https://test.localhost");   
 curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE );
 curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
 curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );

 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

 $data = curl_exec($ch);
 if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
 {
   echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
 }
 var_dump($data);
 exit;
```

Comment: First paste your code

Comment: sorry i cant find your code

Comment: check that post , if it could here you :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24967855/curl-6-could-not-resolve-host-google-com-name-or-service-not-known
 if not , paste your code to see what is the problem .

Comment: Whitelist the calling ip address.

Comment: I do not think this issue is caused by CURL code. As I can CURL to other website. I am trying to CURL to another project in my localhost, that is when I am getting the above error.