# curl works from command line but not in shell script (curl: (6) Could not resolve host: )

Tags: curl, sh, ubuntu-14.04

I'm working in Ubuntu 14.04 and I've this curl invocation ...

```
curl 'http://www.webglobes.org/cesarefortelegram/Telegram/OpenProntoSoccorsi/API/getProntoSoccorsoDetailsByMunicipality.php?municipality=Torino&distance=0'
```

... that works fine from command line, but if I use it in a shell script

```
  #!/bin/bash
  set -x
  .....
  .....
  /usr/bin/curl  'http://www.webglobes.org/cesarefortelegram/Telegram/OpenProntoSoccorsi/API/getProntoSoccorsoDetailsByMunicipality.php?municipality=Torino&distance=0'
  .....
  .....
```

I obtain this error

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.webglobles.org
```

How may I solve? Suggestions?

Comment: Your error message says "webglobles" instead of "webglobes". Did you make a typo?

Comment: oppppppps ..... You're right!!!! Sorry!!!

Comment: No worries, it happens :)

Answer (score 0):

Its is working fine from My ubuntu 14.04 version from both command line and shell script. Something related to DNS, please refer below

[curl: (6) Could not resolve host: google.com; Name or service not known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24967855/curl-6-could-not-resolve-host-google-com-name-or-service-not-known)