# curl: (6) Could not resolve host: on WSL

Tags: curl, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on WSL.

I'm trying to run the following command:

```
curl https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch
```

It fails with error:

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: developer.mozilla.org

I have tried something else, and it worked, e.g.

```
$ curl https://google.com
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="https://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Here's some details:

```
$ nslookup developer.mozilla.org
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
developer.mozilla.org   canonical name = d1avawhiqh9uo1.cloudfront.net.
Name:   d1avawhiqh9uo1.cloudfront.net
Address: 52.84.112.124
Name:   d1avawhiqh9uo1.cloudfront.net
Address: 52.84.112.61
Name:   d1avawhiqh9uo1.cloudfront.net
Address: 52.84.112.82
Name:   d1avawhiqh9uo1.cloudfront.net
Address: 52.84.112.105
Name:   d1avawhiqh9uo1.cloudfront.net
Address: 2600:9000:203c:8e00:13:e62f:2040:93a1
Name:   d1avawhiqh9uo1.cloudfront.net
Address: 2600:9000:203c:9c00:13:e62f:2040:93a1
Name:   d1avawhiqh9uo1.cloudfront.net
Address: 2600:9000:203c:a000:13:e62f:2040:93a1
Name:   d1avawhiqh9uo1.cloudfront.net
Address: 2600:9000:203c:d800:13:e62f:2040:93a1
Name:   d1avawhiqh9uo1.cloudfront.net
Address: 2600:9000:203c:f600:13:e62f:2040:93a1
Name:   d1avawhiqh9uo1.cloudfront.net
Address: 2600:9000:203c:200:13:e62f:2040:93a1
Name:   d1avawhiqh9uo1.cloudfront.net
Address: 2600:9000:203c:1c00:13:e62f:2040:93a1
Name:   d1avawhiqh9uo1.cloudfront.net
Address: 2600:9000:203c:4e00:13:e62f:2040:93a1
```

Please help to understand the problem.

Comment: Can you restart wsl, and run `nslookup developer.mozilla.org` ?

Comment: @Philippe here's the output: https://hastebin.com/mokayariqa.yaml

Comment: Sorry I cannot access hastebin, can you paste in your post ?

Comment: @Philippe added

Comment: You might want to take a look : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24967855/curl-6-could-not-resolve-host-google-com-name-or-service-not-known

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4731#issuecomment-562935992

> This is happening to me after my pc goes to sleep for long hours. Shutting down wsl2 (wsl.exe --shutdown) and open it again solves the problem until the next time the pc goes to sleep again for long hours.

Comment: Thanks for the link, `wsl.exe --shutdown` didn't solve it for me, but `sc stop cmservice && sc stop hns && sc stop vmcompute && sc stop lxssmanager` did.

Comment: After restart wsl I just open wsl with user permission rather than admin

Comment: I had to reboot PC.

Answer (score 19):

The accepted solution didn't work for me.

Searching a little bit more made me land on
[WSL throws (6) Could not resolve host: raw.githubusercontent.com when trying to install NVM and cant ping google.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74635959/wsl-throws-6-could-not-resolve-host-raw-githubusercontent-com-when-trying-to)

and it worked for me. See the answer quoted below

> you can try running this
>
> ```
> sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
> sudo bash -c 'echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf'
> sudo bash -c 'echo "[network]" > /etc/wsl.conf'
> sudo bash -c 'echo "generateResolvConf = false" >> /etc/wsl.conf'
> sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
> ```
>
> it deletes your resolve.config file thats automatically generated when
> u run WSL then creates a new file and puts "nameserver 8.8.8.8", then
> creates a wsl.conf file and adds [network] and generateResolveConf =
> false to prevent auto generation of that file
>
> then
>
> ping google.com

Comment: Damn this is really dumb. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: To fix `chattr: Operation not supported while reading flags on /etc/resolv.conf` add `-f` flag to the last command

Answer (score 7):

For me it happened after the Windows 11 upgrade.

I had to update i `/etc/wsl.conf` and restart my WSL instance

```
[network]
generateResolvConf = true
```

Answer (score 4):

**Problem:** While my pc was connected to the VPN, WSL Network manager kept overwriting */etc/resolv.conf*. This prevented me from downloading packages that can make *resolv.conf* immutable.

**My Solution:**
Run a script in bash shell that constantly updates *resovl.conf*. Concurrently, in a separate shell, download packages that can make *resolv.conf* immutable. See steps 4 & 5.

**STEPS:**

1. **Get DNS server addresses**
   In powershell run:
   `ipconfig /all`
2. **Rank Interface Metric every time you reconnect to VPN**
   *My VPN is: Cisco AnyConnect*
   In powershell run:
   `Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object {$_.InterfaceDescription -Match "Cisco AnyConnect"} | Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceMetric 6000`
   To Automate this see: [Create Windows Scheduled Task for Auto update](https://gist.github.com/balmeida-nokia/122adf625c11c916902950e3255bd104#automatic-configuration)
3. **Update wsl.conf**
   In WSL shell as root user `sudo su -` run:

```
echo "[network]
generateResolvConf=false" >> /etc/wsl.conf;
```

4. **Update resolv.conf with correct DNS IPs**
   Script loops 300 times, pausing for 1 second in between.
   *Replace xx.xx... in script below with actual IPs from **step 1**.*
   ***Run *step 5* concurrently!***
   In WSL shell as root user `sudo su -` run:

```
for i in {1..300}; do
  echo '# non-vpn DNS IP
nameserver 8.8.8.8
# cisco any connect vpn DNS IPs
nameserver xx.xx.xx.xx
nameserver xx.xx.xx.xx' > /etc/resolv.conf;
  sleep 1;
done
```

5. **Download Packages and Make resolv.conf immutable**
   *NOTE: My WSL Distro is Fedora you may need to use a different package manager*.
   In separate WSL shell as root user `sudo su -` run:

```
dnf -y install e2fsprogs
chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

**Troubleshooting:**

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf                    # check content
chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf              # make resolve.conf editable
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same on VM, was different reason though. Add

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
```

to

> /etc/resolv.conf

Answer (score 0):

for posterity ...
(
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal)

the work around for wsl2 in windows 10 and trying to reach localhost is :

`"cmd.exe /C curl http://127.0.0.1 ..."`

Answer (score 0):

Find DNS entry from window command and add it to */etc/resolv.conf* file of ubuntu using its terminal. Restart then *ping google.com* to validate.